# Why angular 2 http returns Observable of Response and where is it set

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In source of Angular2 Http module i found function called **httpRequest** that returns Observable of Response:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.1/modules/%40angular/http/src/http.ts#L18

This method uses method of abstract class ConnectionBackend called **createConnection** and returns property **response** type of any of class Connection.
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.1/modules/%40angular/http/src/interfaces.ts#L32

My question is - where is this property **response** sets to Observable of Response? 
Where is this part of code contains something like

```
response = Observable.create(...)
```

Comment: Here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.3/modules/%40angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L86-L93

Comment: also: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.1/modules/%40angular/http/src/backends/jsonp_backend.ts#L65

Comment: Thank you both! Realy missed this implementations of Connection class.